# same form in different tabs on jsp page

Tags: html, jsp, servlet-3.0

Based on the number of input i want multiple froms tab to appear on same page in jsp. I am new to this so please help. Below is the image what i want to implement. It is done in .net

[image: The input was three so three tabs appeared on the same page.]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the TabView component from YUI JavaScript library.
 http://yui.github.io/yui2/docs/yui_2.9.0_full/examples/tabview/frommarkup.html

Inside every tab, you can then insert anything you want, including forms, text content etc.